# How to use redis for Laravel Passport token storage and authentication instead of MySQL

Tags: mysql, redis, laravel-passport

I'm trying to remove queries to dB on each API requests that have Token generated using Laravel Passport.

Since all tokens are saved in dB, on each request dB hit would be high bottle-neck to performance.

How would I put all tokens along with associated user data in redis and fetch user associated from redis instead of MySQL?

Comment: How many requests per second are you talking about? If it's under 1000 it won't matter. The database can handle it.

Comment: more than 1K requests/sec.

Comment: Other systems use cryptographically signed cookies which avoids the database/Redis entirely.

Comment: For now, I would be happy with redis implementation :). If you could guide me in regard to this.

Comment: @SujitBaniya Have you found any solution for this? It's getting really annoying.